# Spring session jdbc fails to start

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to configure a database stored session with spring session in a sprinboot application

I have already created tables spring_session and spring_session_attributes, however it fails to start:

These are my properties:

```
spring.session.jdbc.table-name:SPRING_SESSION
spring.datasource.driver-class-name:org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:postgresql://my_server:my_port/my_schema
spring.datasource.username:my_user
spring.datasource.password:my_password
```

This is the exception that I get:

```
11:47:56.276 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.~.SpringApplication - Application startup failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration$SessionRepositoryValidator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'jdbc')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'jdbc')
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration$SessionRepositoryValidator.checkSessionRepository(SessionAutoConfiguration.java:103) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.IitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Why you identify table name in property file ?

Comment: It is what documentation says: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add jpa library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

That was enough

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url.jdbc=postgresql://my_server:my_port/my_schema
spring.datasource.username=my_user
spring.datasource.password=my_password
```

this is example of using spring boot with mysql 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

and application.properties looks like

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```